# Wireless Security Pen testing Setup

Tags: hardware, wireless

I had a Asus N82J laptop with a dual boot setup.  I boot into Kali and Windows 7.  Long story short because of my dual boot with Grub I corrupted my HDD the operating system kept moving blocks of memory around.  I've obtained a new SSD and 2nd drive HDD and starting from scratch.  I still want the functionality of Kali Linux to see my wireless.  I've install VMWare work station 10 and I have a VM with Kali in it with a Windows 7 host.  I have a USB external Alfa antenna AWUS036NH which seems like a bit of work getting the drivers for this.  Is this the best setup for wireless pentesting?  Or is native Kali Linux the best route?  I have to have a Windows OS as I'm a MS developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As VMWare workstation provides USB Passthrough, it *should* be fine using USB wireless cards and doing testing from a kali/linux Virtual Machine.

I say *should* as there's always a risk of bugs in how VMWare passes the data through to the guest VM, so it could have an impact in some circumstances.  That said, my experience of VMWare Workstation and using USB devices in guests has been pretty positive, so yep overall I'd say that's a reasonable solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response it took me a while to build the dual boot system and at the end of the day I'd do it again but no way to cleanly back it up.  I'll keep going forward with this build with the VMWare. Thanks again.